# Java enum constructor error

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an `enum` class so that I can use each value in a for loop, getting each value one at a time.

This is my `enum` declaration:

```
public enum SpaceStyle {

    public SpaceStyle(spaceStyle1, spaceStyle2, spaceStyle3);
    private String key;

    SpaceStyle(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

This is the `for` loop where I want to loop and use each method.

```
for (SpaceStyle key : SpaceStyle.values()) {
    Map<String, String> contentMap = createContentMap(conf, versionNumber, data);
    createAndPopulateSpace(conf, versionNumber, contentMap, key.toString());
}

// The final method where the key of the enum will be used.
public StudioResponse createSpace(ProductInstance conf, VersionNumber \
            versionNumber, String spaceName, String spaceKey, String key) {
    return conf.buildRequest("/createspace.action")
        .setArg("name", spaceName)
        .setArg("key", spaceKey)
        .setArg("permissionSetter.registeredCanView", "true")
        .setArg("permissionSetter.registeredCanEdit", "true")
        .setArg("themeKey", "com.atlassian.studio.confluence" + key)
        .execute("Creating space '" + spaceName + "'");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to know if you did it "correctly" without know what it is you want it to do.

Comment: i just want to pass each enum value to the createspace method. so i wrote a for loop to action the method for each enum value.

Answer (score 6):

That won't compile, because you can't have a public constructor in an enum.

This will compile:

```
public enum SpaceStyle {
    spaceStyle1("some-key"),
    spaceStyle2("some-other-key"),
    spaceStyle3("foo-bar");

    private String key;

    private SpaceStyle(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}
```